# Swift how to wait for an action to be complete?

Tags: ios, swift, action, wait

I have a function which create a sequence of actions. After this function, an other function is called with another sequence as well.

I would like to call the second function when the actions of the first function are completely terminated.

I tried some solutions with a "Do.. While" but it doesn't work because it stops the action.. I don't know by the way.. 
I tried to use semaphore but it doesn't work as well..
I tried to use "completion" in action and put my second function in but it doesn't work...

So I am lost, I don't know how to do.. A thing I know also is the duration of the sequence so maybe there is a solution to wait this duration until to launch the second function.. ?

Could you help me please ?

Comment: Show some code you have tried so far.

Comment: You could use completionHandler (blocks), but it could be good to show your action, because you don't say it, but I guess there are async calls.

Comment: Your question is so vague that it's unanswerable. What do you mean by "actions"? Are you talking animations? Post the relevant code, along with a description of what you're actually trying to accomplish in concrete terms. Otherwise this question needs to be closed as unclear.

Answer (score 2):

I am talking about moveTo action. In fact, I would want to finish a moveTo action before to call a function after that..

Here is the code:

```
        self.fct_utils.direction = false
        coord_b = self.verifyAngle()

        let wait = fct_move.nodeWaitForDuration(1)
        let action = fct_move.nodeMoveTo(backTime, coord_x: coord_b.x, coord_y: coord_b.y)

        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([wait, action, wait])

        robot.runAction(sequence)
```

And I would to finish this sequence before to call the next line which is :

```
    self.fct_utils.direction = true
```